# Regex is not working with Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, regex, linq

i have the following code

```
Regex R = new Regex("my regex");
var q = from c in db.tble1
        where R.IsMatch(c.text)
        select c;
```

and while debugging i saw in the q result this message

> Method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."}    System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}

so what have i done wrong ?

Edit:I learned that the method has no supported translation to SQL
but how to solve this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regex has no supported translation to SQL. The error says it all. You can't use regex in LINQ to SQL.

Try using a `like` or `substring` comparison instead:

```
var q = from c in db.tble1
        where c.text.StartsWith("x") && c.text.Substring(2, 1) == "y"
        select c;
```

Or, you could perform an in memory regex comparison. You can do this by calling `ToList()` before using the `Regex`:

```
Regex R = new Regex("my regex");
var q = from c in db.tble1.ToList()
        where R.IsMatch(c.text)
        select c;
```

Comment: @Star yes, but again: TSQL **does not support** regex. The only option left is a SQL-CLR function that you write and install on the server, and it won't be efficient (it will table scan)